# I want to embed video by url in php landing page

Tags: javascript, php, video, video-streaming

This is a video URL

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/oZQBTwwbQKCuK346RgySUhXsve331f0LYNsFaf7coxCJd_zLN7n7LtTJj3rHBZ7eGBmNVYnbm94_hpb1Nbp1wpVx-PKqbkBkkuMuyPmAuiHInyctaJwuzPn8yzxU_hApAjjomS9A=m22?cpn=GpvVeTPeeVJK_253&c=WEB_EMBEDDED_PLAYER&cver=20200415
```

It can be opened in Firefox browser, but I want to open this video by URL in PHP landing page.

Comment: tested with iframe its not working...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Aight, seems like google does not want you to embed videos from googleusercontent on any non-google pages. IMO the best possibility would be to upload it to youtube (you can do that right from Google Photos) and simply not list it, that way you can only access it with the link. Furthermore youtube videos are really easy to embed on a website. Refering to this: https://support.google.com/culturalinstitute/partners/answer/6056695?hl=en

Have you tried using HTML and the video tag?
If not, try this:

```
$videourl = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/oZQBTwwbQKCuK346RgySUhXsve331f0LYNsFaf7coxCJd_zLN7n7LtTJj3rHBZ7eGBmNVYnbm94_hpb1Nbp1wpVx-PKqbkBkkuMuyPmAuiHInyctaJwuzPn8yzxU_hApAjjomS9A=m22?cpn=GpvVeTPeeVJK_253&c=WEB_EMBEDDED_PLAYER&cver=20200415';
$html = '<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="' . $videourl . '" type="video/ogg"></video>';
print_r($html);
```

Also, try the following url as $videourl:

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/oZQBTwwbQKCuK346RgySUhXsve331f0LYNsFaf7coxCJd_zLN7n7LtTJj3rHBZ7eGBmNVYnbm94_hpb1Nbp1wpVx-PKqbkBkkuMuyPmAuiHInyctaJwuzPn8yzxU_hApAjjomS9A=m22?cpn=GpvVeTPeeVJK_253&cver=20200415
```

This one is not using the web embedded player, you gotta change the tag too though.